# C# : Based on a start date and number of Months/Fortnights, calculate the appropriate dates

Tags: c#, .net, regex, linq, logic

I have a list of dates between a given start and end date which are either month-end dates or the 15th of each month. I want to filter out all the dates that start with the 15th. Is there any way to achieve this in C#?

I was thinking about converting all the dates in the dataset into strings and iterating through the list and running a regular expression (which I will need help with) which will remove the dates starting with 15 from the list. Is there a better approach to this problem?

Comment: Use `DateTime` objects, not strings.

Comment: you are supposed to show the code you have tried already, so we can help you with your attempt. Asking for a solution to a general problem is considered rude. This is not a code writing service. This is a help forum. This is why your question is getting downvoted.

Comment: `dates.Where(d => d.Day != 15)`

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay don't forget .ToList() `dates = dates.Where(d => d.Day != 15).ToList();`

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. I was so tunneled into converting the dates into strings that I didn't even consider that I can use a simple getter of the DateTime class to achieve this.

Thanks for your suggestion. Have a good one and stay safe.

Comment: @MortenBork I am sorry if this sounded rude but I had hit a roadblock and I wasn't exactly sure how to proceed with it. I was looking for an approach rather than a ready-made code. Thanks for your response.

Comment: @MathewHD thanks for your help. The solution was so easy that I actually look stupid having asked this question. However, in my defense, I was convinced that converting the dates into strings and then applying a regex was the way to go, so I didn't even consider other easier possibilities. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @MathewHD That entirely depends on what the OP needs to do with the result. `ToList()` may well be superfluous.

Comment: I assumed, if his base idea was removing elements from the list, that he needs a list.

Comment: I managed to come up with a solution without using lists and I've added it in the question. I am unable to add it as an answer, since the question was poorly framed and marked as closed. Could anyone help me open this question so that I can post that code as an answer?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies for the poorly worded question. Here's what we wanted to do.
Given a start date, we had a drop-down to select if we want to calculate a previous date based on a Monthly/Fortnightly basis. The Monthly date always had to be the Month end date and fortnightly date had to be the 15th. Following is the code that computes this.

The parameters:
dtAsOnDate is the Start Date
interval is the Monthly/Fortnightly
numberOfIntervals is the Number of Months/Fortnights that we need to go back to.

For an instance, if I select 31-Mar-2020 as my start date, Fortnightly as my interval and 3 as my number of Intervals, the code now returns 15-Feb-2020 (4 fortnights before 31 March, 31 March being the first fortnight)

```
public static List<string> GetDate(DateTime dtAsOnDate, string interval, int numberOfIntervals)
        {
            DateTime currDate = dtAsOnDate;
            DateTime startDate = currDate.AddMonths(-numberOfIntervals);
            DateTime endDate = currDate;
            Func<DateTime, bool> condition = null;
            if (interval == "Monthly")
            {
                if (dtAsOnDate.Day == 15)
                    condition = date => date.Day == 15;
                else
                    condition = date => date.Day == DateTime.DaysInMonth(date.Year, date.Month);
            }
            else
            {
                condition = date => date.Day == 15 || date.Day == DateTime.DaysInMonth(date.Year, date.Month);
            }
            return Enumerable.Range(0, (endDate - startDate).Days + 1)
                     .Select(index => startDate.AddDays(index))
                     .Where(condition)
                     .TakeWhile(date => date <= endDate)
                     .OrderByDescending(date => date)
                     .Take(numberOfIntervals)
                     .Select(date => date.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy"))
                     .ToList();

        }
```